# How to hide the hard-coded system account username/password in reactjs (Web Front End) for connecting directly to Mongodb

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, authentication

In a web application, normally the web front end calls the backend api service with some security token. With that token, server side api service can authenticate the front end without problem.

However, when I read the [Web-Queue-Worker architecture style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/architecture-styles/web-queue-worker) from Microsoft Azure Application Architecture Guide, from the diagram you can see that it suggests a possible direct database connection from the web front end to backend database server, let's assume they are reactjs and mongodb.

The question is, if such connection is implemented, how can the web front end hides the username/password of mongodb server account? Assuming there is one single system account only for the web front end to connect to mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using mongoose and creating a UserSchema of some sort in which case you can communicate to the schema not to display the password  like so:

```js
    password: {
        type: String, 
        select: false, // will hide the password
        required: "password is required",
        minlength: 6,
    },
```

Comment: The username/password is not the end user's account and an account belongs to the web front end.

Comment: in that case you need to create a new model and reflect the values into it, leaving out the password field

Answer (score -1):

I usually use ***`.env`*** file for this case.